# Show SharePoint Online List Views as Tabs on a Modern Page with Security

Tags: listview, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-list, spfx-extension

I've just started doing SPFx development and one of my first task is to come up with a webpart to show modern list views as tabs with security. Only specific groups having access to the view should be able to view it. I tried searching and couldn't find anything useful. We use hillbilly tabs today in classic UI and would like to replicate the functionality. I'm also open to ideas on how we can implement security for modern list views and show them on a single page for the end user as a local dashboard.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Link : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/detailslist
I hope it may help you to start with.

use pnp to fetch group or user permission.
you may use (React-bootstrap-tab) https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/
if you coudn't find any tab  control in ofice ui fabric.